# RabbitMq(bunny): Rabbitmq deleting message from queue . acknowledgement not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rabbitmq, bunny

I am processing records from my rabbitMQ. in order to avoid loss of messages from rabbitMQ i am using rabbitMQ acknowledgment strategey. For testing purpose i have raises the exception just before the code where i gave acknowledgment back to the rabbitMQ. as per the code that i have written rabbitMQ should not delete the message from queue untile the line in my code i.e "c.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)" is executed. Below is my code

```
begin
MessageService.with_channel do |c|  
  queue = c.queue(QUEUE_NAME, :durable => true)
  exchange = c.topic(TOPIC_NAME, :durable => true)
  queue.bind(exchange, :routing_key => "#{ROUTING_KEY_PREFIX}.#")
  available_messages = queue.message_count
  processed_messages = 0
  fact_object = {}
  while queue.message_count > 0 && processed_messages <= message_limit
    queue.pop(:manual_ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
      rad_exam_hash_object = JSON.parse(payload)
      entity_manager,criteria = self.query_revenue_cost_calculation(rad_exam_hash_object)
      fact_object = self.revenue_cost_calculation_result(entity_manager,criteria)
      self.insert_data_into_table(fact_object)
      raise "exception"
      c.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
    end
    processed_messages = processed_messages + 1
    available_messages = processed_messages - 1
  end
  [processed_messages, available_messages,fact_object]
end
rescue
  puts "got exception while processing messages"
end
```

Please help me in undestnding why rabbitMQ is deleting message from queue even if the line "c.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)" is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know ruby.
Messages are deleted from queue:

- if queue is deleted
- if they are acknowledged
- if message TTL expires.

So if it's non of that, maybe it's in the way the `pop` works. This sounds to be calling AMQPs `get` and (based on the tutorials) `subscribe` seems to be calling AMQPs `consume`.